# HTML: center a div's contents horizontally and vertically?

Tags: html, css

I read a bunch of things to try, but still can't get this working. I have a div with some contents, I'd like the contents to be centered vertically and horizontally. When I do the below, they center vertically, but justify to the left. If I remove the `display: table-cell`, they center horizontally but justify to the top.

```
<div class='contents'>
  <span>a span</span><br>
  <span>b span</span><br>
  <span>c span</span>
</div>

.contents {
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: seems to be fine here https://jsfiddle.net/hwtt9c01/

Comment: Yep - http://jsfiddle.net/wm3ktgcv/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your example and this is working fine. Is it in a certain browser that it is not working for you?

```css
.contents {
  height:100px;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='contents'>
  <span>a span</span>
  <br>
  <span>b span bit longer</span>
  <br>
  <span>c span</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, it works if width is set. I'll mark this answer as correct when I can.

Comment: @ab11 it's not the width. If you remove the width in this example it still works. (I've done this just now)

Answer (score 1):

You probably have another CSS declaration that has a higher specificity. Here's an example:

```css
#container div {
  text-align:left;  
}
.contents {
  height: 100px;
  width:100px;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class='contents'>
    <span>a span</span>
    <br>
    <span>splurge b span</span>
    <br>
    <span>c span</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[This article](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) might help too.